# Join columns side by side in result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like my result to look something like this

```
    FirstName1     LastName1         FirstName2      LastName2
       Amy           Smith              Bob            Stone
      Fred           Joker              Gina           White
```

Where FirstName1 and FirstName2 have same data types but nothing I can use to join (assume no one has same names) and the same goes for LastName1 and LastName2. 
I tried to create 2 tables. First table contains FirstName1 and LastName1. Second table contains Firstname2 and LastName2. 
Then I use

```
SELECT table1.FirstName1, table1.LastName1, table2.FirstName2, table2.LastName2
FROM table1, table2;
```

But this gives me a lot of duplicates. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you exactly triing to archive? If you want to join two tables, you need to do with some information. The database can't read in your mind and do this for you.

Comment: @NLemay, I guess I am really just trying to make my result set looks pretty. Can that be done? The only thing I found in common is that the max row of all 4 fields is 10. Can I join on the row number?

Comment: Thank you for the example you added. But why "Amy Smith" goes with "Bob Stone" and "Fred Joker" with "Gina White" ? You want first of table1 with first of table2, and then second of table1 with second of table2 ?

Comment: @NLemay, The 1st set of names(first1+last1) are ORDER BY Firstname1 and the 2nd set of names(first2+last2) are ORDER BY Firstname2. They really don't have anything in common that I can use to join.. :(

Comment: what DBMS are you using? SQLServer/Oracle/MySQL?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. What does the original table look like? What does your output look like right now (with the duplicates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.FirstName1, t1.LastName1, t2.FirstName2, t2.LastName2
FROM
    (SELECT 
         FirstName1, 
         LastName1, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName1) 'RowNumber'
     FROM table1
    ) AS t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         FirstName2, 
         LastName2, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName2) 'RowNumber'
     FROM table2
    ) AS t2
    ON t1.RowNumber = t2.RowNumber
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN` will handle the cases where the number of rows from the two tables are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
But I am getting an error at ROW_NUMBER(). It says **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**

Comment: what version of oracle are you using? The `ROW_NUMBER()` function usage can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm, btw.

Comment: I am using.. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0

Comment: @Dino55 - please look at your code.  Vikdor's syntax is valid, so you have introduced a syntax error when transposing his example to your actual tables.

Comment: should really have an easy function like cbind in R; its as simple as cbind(col1,col2)

Answer (score 0):

You should never do what you're trying to do, but try to use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT Distinct 
    table1.FirstName1, 
    table1.LastName1, 
    table2.FirstName2, 
    table2.LastName2
FROM table1, table2;
```

The problem with your approach is that the retrieved dataset doesn't make any sense.  Why do you want to do it like this anyways?

Edit: you can always do this do this:

```
select table1.FirstName1, table1.LastName1, table2.FirstName2, table2.LastName2
from table1, table2   
where table1.rownum= table2.rownum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately that still gives me duplicate rows....

Comment: @Dino55, can you show sample data. And what you want the result to be?

Comment: @Dino55, now I understand what you're trying to do, and it's not hard to do, but can you tell us WHY do you want to do that? what's the end goal? show it on the report? send it to the UI for the user to see? maybe we can suggest better approach

Comment: @Dino55, and also, what dbms are you using?

Comment: @Dino55, and see my edit please for the possible solution

Comment: Oh haha I am really just trying to make it looks pretty. I am used to programming in C and Java where all kinds of output are pretty possible. It's no biggie if this cannot be done :)

Comment: DBMS? umm.. I am using Oracle Database with SQLPLUS?

Comment: I tried your way but I get errors on the rownum variables.
**ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification**

Answer (score 0):

> "Oh haha I am really just trying to make it looks pretty. I am used to
>   programming in C and Java where all kinds of output are pretty
>   possible. "

Database programming is different.  In this realm *content* is more important than mere prettiness.  So when it comes to result sets the database insists that all the columns in a row share a meaningful relationship (the clue is in the name, relational database).

Your problem is, you have no tables with no key in common and hence no way to join the two sets of rows together.  Without a proper WHERE clause the database implements a cross join, i.e. a cartesian product, and that's where all the duplication comes from.

Given that you don't have meaningful keys your only option is to fake them; [the approach shown by Vikdor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427592/146325) is one way to achieve this.